# How to set a var for a Docker-compose file?

Tags: variables, docker, docker-compose

I made an application and I need to test it on our lab. My colleague has done a `docker-compose.yml` file but nobody is at office today and I'm lost with a line in this file:

```
image: gitlab-${DOCKERADM_ENV}:5005/rims/mgmt-docker-gui:lab
```

Because when I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose-mgmt.yml pull` I have an error `DOCKERADM_ENV is not set`.

I want to set this variable but how can I do that ?

Comment: You have to set the variable I  your environment before running it. Try `export DOCKERADM_ENV=foo`.

Comment: It would work too but @Lauri were faster, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's read from environment variables, so you can use:
`DOCKERADM_ENV=<value> docker-compose -f docker-compose-mgmt.yml pull`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting environment variable

For windows ,

```
SET DOCKERADM_ENV=boo
```

For OS X or Linux:

```
export DOCKERADM_ENV=boo
```